# How can I search for value in entity by column name?

Tags: arrays, symfony, object, variables, entity

I am trying to find a value inside my table row by column name:

```
$entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($EntityName)->findOneBy(['uuid' => $uuid]);
$result = $entity->getCat();
```

The difficulty is, that I want to have the ability to make the replace "Cat" with a variable.

This is unfortunately not possible:

```
$myvariable = "Cat";
$result = $entity->'get'.$myvariable.();
```

So I made another approach:

```
$entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($EntityName)->findBy(array('uuid' => $uuid));
$result = array_search($myvariable, $entity);
```

But here I get an empty output.

Another approach:

```
 foreach ($entity as $key => $value) {
     if($myvariable == $key){
            $result = $value;
     }
  }
```

The error message here is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Documents could
>   not be converted to string").

I just have difficulties to find the right way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [variable function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

```
$myvariable = "getCat";
$result = $entity->$myvariable();
```

Comment: I did this   `$myvariable= "get".$name;$getObj = (string) $myvariable; $result = $entity->$getObj();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this with reflection. Here simple example

```
<?php

class ClassName
{

    private $property1;
    private $property2;

    public function __construct($property1, $property2)
    {
        $this->property1 = $property1;
        $this->property2 = $property2;
    }

    public function getProperty1()
    {
        return $this->property1;
    }

    public function getProperty2()
    {
        return $this->property2;
    }
}


$class = new ClassName('test1', 'test2');

$field = 'property2';

$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($class);

if ($reflectionClass->hasProperty($field)) {
    $property = $reflectionClass->getProperty($field);
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    echo $property->getValue($class);
}

// or

echo $class->{sprintf('get%s', ucfirst($field))}();
```

Comment: Wow, this is so complicated. There is no simple solution?

Comment: Updated the answer with a simpler example. Reflection is an interesting thing, you should read about it.